# Data did n't load in firebase app properly

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I created an app using firebase on android studio.There is a searchview will appear after authentication with mobile otp. When user search on search view it will filter the results and goes to a recyclerview and so on. At the first time launch of activity(ie.,home activity after auth) app works perfectly.

But my problem is my app didn't load data after some time later.Also other fields including searchview also didn't work. Also,App works after logout and sign in again to the app after happened this problem.

Anybody know how to fix it?

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {
private SearchView search;
View view;
DatabaseReference dataRef;
private  FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter;
ListView mListView;
private TextView text;
ArrayList<String> city=new ArrayList<String>();
private int i=0;
private String data,val,var;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ProgressBar progressBar;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_home,container,false);
    if (container!=null){
        container.removeAllViews();
    }
    progressBar= (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.search_pro);
    search= (SearchView) v.findViewById(R.id.search);
    search.onActionViewExpanded();
    search.setIconified(false);
    search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    search.setQueryHint("Search Docter By City Or Department");
    mListView= (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.mList);
    mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    dataRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Docters");
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    dataRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            data=dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
            val=dataSnapshot.child("department").getValue(String.class);
            if (!city.contains(data)){
                city.add(data);
            }
            if (!city.contains(val)){
                city.add(val);
            }
            search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            data=dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
            val=dataSnapshot.child("department").getValue(String.class);
            city.add(data);
            city.add(val);
            city.add(var);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            if (!text.isEmpty()){
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            }else{
                mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            return false;
        }

    });

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String itemRef = (String) adapter.getItem(position);
            search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            FragmentTransaction ft=getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            DocterList fragment=new DocterList();
            Bundle item=new Bundle();
            item.putString("item",itemRef);
            fragment.setArguments(item);
            ft.replace(R.id.activity_fragment_home,fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: it's hard to figure out the problem without the code

Comment: `Sure that the problem which arises is not due to my code` : how can you be so sure ?

Comment: Because of the app works a long time perfectly even i close the app and start again.

Comment: If you wants to see the code,i will post soon...

Comment: @mrid => check it now...

Answer (score 0):

All code you have written in  `onCreateView` should be written in `onViewCreated`.

It's better to do any assignment of subviews to fields in onViewCreated. This is because the framework does an automatic null check for you to ensure that your Fragment's view hierarchy has been created and inflated.

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {
    private SearchView search;
    View v;
    DatabaseReference dataRef;
    private  FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter;
    ListView mListView;
    private TextView text;
    ArrayList<String> city=new ArrayList<String>();
    private int i=0;
    private String data,val,var;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_home,container,false);
        if (container!=null){
            container.removeAllViews();
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    progressBar= (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.search_pro);
    search= (SearchView) v.findViewById(R.id.search);
    search.onActionViewExpanded();
    search.setIconified(false);
    search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    search.setQueryHint("Search Docter By City Or Department");
    mListView= (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.mList);
    mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

dataRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Docters");
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
dataRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        data=dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
        val=dataSnapshot.child("department").getValue(String.class);
        if (!city.contains(data)){
            city.add(data);
        }
        if (!city.contains(val)){
            city.add(val);
        }
        search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        data=dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
        val=dataSnapshot.child("department").getValue(String.class);
        city.add(data);
        city.add(val);
        city.add(var);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
        if (!text.isEmpty()){
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
        }else{
            mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return false;
    }

});

mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String itemRef = (String) adapter.getItem(position);
        search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        FragmentTransaction ft=getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        DocterList fragment=new DocterList();
        Bundle item=new Bundle();
        item.putString("item",itemRef);
        fragment.setArguments(item);
        ft.replace(R.id.activity_fragment_home,fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
    }
});
    }
```

`progressBar= (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.search_pro);` ==> the view will only come into existence in `onViewCreated`

Comment: is this fix the problem?

Comment: @Suhail I don't have the entire code, so can't be sure